# Are there useful pmf/pdf factorizations if a subset of n random variables are mutually indepenent?

Tags: density-function, independence, multivariate-distribution

Example: Consider 3 discrete random variables X,Y,Z with pmf's denoted by P.  If X and Y are mutually independent, then P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y).  Is there a useful way to factor P(X,Y,Z) using the info that X and Y are mutually independent?

In general, is there a useful factorization for the case of n random variables where k less than n of the random variables are mutually independent?

Comment: The last sentence of the question seems incomplete.

Comment: $p(x,y,z) = p(z|x,y)p(x,y)=p(z|x,y)p(x)p(y)$. You can apply the same decomposition for any number of dependent and independent variables. Eg $p(a,b,c,d,e)=p(a,b|c,d,e)p(c)p(d)p(e)$ if $c,d,e$ are independent.

Comment: @smith so you've just used the definition of conditional probability to condition on the variables which are mutually independent.  Then you used the definition of mutual independence to factor an unconditioned multivariate distribution into a product of univariate distributions.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala for come reason using < caused an issue.  I replaced the < with "less than".

Comment: @user3731622 You got it.